# Python remove everything after a space with hex \x00

Tags: python, string

I have a variable string with unknown length that has the important string at the left side and the unimportant things on the right side separated by a single space. How do I remove the unimportant information to the right?

I have tried rstrip, and split with no success.

**Edit**: I'll place the actual value that needs to be fixed.

```
"NPC_tester_contact() ) ntact()                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "
```

The very first space (the one left to the closed parenthesis) should have everything after including itself be marked as unimportant.

**Edit**: The output should be "`NPC_tester_contact()`"!

Look carefully at my string that I placed above. There is alot of whitespace after it as well. I assume that is what is causing the hiccup.

I have tried most of the solutions here and they either don't do anything or just produce whitespace.

`repr(s)` gives me.

```
'NPC_me_lvup_event_contact()\x00t()\x00act()\x00act()\x00ntact()\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

It should be "`NPC_me_lvup_event_contact()`".

Thanks!

Perhaps this is a better question. Is there a way to remove all characters after the first \x00 hex that shows up in the string?

For some reason, it works sometimes and doesn't always work. The above example was done with the method that Levon posted.

Solution: Problem solved. This is more of a null byte rather than a space byte. The solution would of been any of the below using "\x00" as the identifier instead of " ".

Thank you everyone!

Comment: can you show your code here? It would help to see what's going on over there :)

Comment: I don't have any code other than modelfile = stringdb.read(256).

Comment: @user1150764 where is stringdb coming from?

Comment: That's from the open file that Python opens. It's basically a binary table that python reads directly from.

Comment: Could you post the results of `repr(s)` where s is your string?  Many of the things people have posted should work fine, which makes me suspect that your space might not really be a space, or something of that sort.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem-- your space isn't a space.  Try `s.split("\x00")` to split on the 0 byte instead and then take the first element -- not the cleanest, but should work.

Comment: It appears to have worked perfectly now. Thank you DSM, for some reason I thought \x00 was a whitespace.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE** based on *new* string data:

Assuming `s` contains your string:

```
s.split('\x00')[0]
```

yields

```
'NPC_me_lvup_event_contact()'
```

[split()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) will give you a list of strings separated by the character you specify with `split`. If none is specified space is used, in this case we use the hex character you are interested in.

Comment: Your method appears to only produce white space. The back of this string has a large amount of whitespace behind it.

Comment: @user1150764 That's very odd, I am copying this straight out of the interpreter, including the output generated for your input. Are you copying my code?

Comment: Thank you Levon. Sorry for the confusion. :) I should just use hex when dealing with binary data.

Comment: @user1150764 .. well, we got it solved. It always helps to post the actual data - made a big difference :)

Answer (score 2):

USE split(' ')[0]

```
 >>> a = 'aaa bbb'
    >>> a.split(' ')[0]
    'aaa'
    >>> >
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> mystring = 'important useless'
>>> mystring[:mystring.find(' ')]
'important'
```

Comment: hmm interesting. It appears to work for the test string that I posted above but not all of the in the table. Will look further in it!

Answer (score 1):

split() w/o delimiter splits by any whitespace:

```
>>> "asdasd         xyz".split()[0]
'asdasd'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the split() function, and get the first item that it returns:

```
raw_string = 'NPC_tester_contact() ) ntact()  '
important = raw_string.split(' ')[0]
```

Will return:

```
NPC_tester_contact()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "important unimportant"
important = str.split(' ')[0]
```

Comment: str is a builtin name so don't use it for variables.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
lhs,rhs=s.split()  #lhs is what you want.
```

This only works if there is really only one space.

Otherwise, you can get `lhs` by (but you lose rhs):

```
lhs=s.split()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, 
*will assume that your string is stored in `str`*
`print str[0:str.index(" ")]`

comment if it dont work, will solve it..

here is

```
My code
str = "NPC_tester_contact() ) ntact()                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "

print str[0:str.index(" ")]

output
NPC_tester_contact()

link
http://ideone.com/i9haI
```

and if you want output to be have surrounded with double-quotes then 
`print '"',str[0:str.index(" ")],'"'

Comment: This doesn't appear to work. Did you try with the example string I posted above? Use all the characters between the quotes!

Answer (score 0):

you could use a regex type solution also. Something like:

```
import re

input_string = 'NPC_me_lvup_event_contact()\x00t()\x00act()\x00act()\x00ntact()\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

string_pat = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z0-9\(\)_]+')
try:
    first_part = string_pat.findall(input_string)[0]
except IndexError:
    # There is nothing of interest for you in this string
    first_part = ''
```